# Cordova Launch Image Changing Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm developing a cordova application in IOS. The problem I'm facing is when I change launch image inside Images.xcassets->LaunchImage.launchimage folder. It's ok if I leave the cordova default images without any edits. But when I edit those images with my own launch image, and runs the app it stops with an error  in xcode "launch image set did not have any applicable content". Please let me know how to change the launch image. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now. I was using InkScape for editing the image. But when I saved, it was saving with a different height and width. Once I corrected the issue everything works ok.